# Injectivity of map in Beilinson's conjectures

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, nt.number-theory, l-functions, motivic-cohomology

In Beilinson's conjectures on special values of L-functions, he uses the image of the motivic cohomology of a a regular proper model in the motivic cohomology of the generic fiber to state the conjectures.

Does anybody know an example that this map is not injective?